# Analysis: limit of $x^n$ if $x\gt 1$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

could someone tell me how I can show $x^n \to \infty$ if $x \gt 1$

From limit to infinity definition

$x^n \to \infty$ if for all $M \gt 0$ there exists an N in the natural numbers such that for all $n \gt N$ then $x^n \gt M$. Given any M how would I find N without taking logs

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $a>1$, prove $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to +\infty}a^x = +\infty}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -\infty} a^x = 0}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317842/if-a1-prove-displaystyle-lim-x-to-inftyax-infty-and-displays).

Comment: By $x$ it is usual to denote the variable, not a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M > 0$ be arbitrary,we may further stipulate that $M > 1$, since $x > 1$ . Since $x > 1$, you can let $x = 1 + a$ with $a > 0$. Apply Bernoulli's inequality first: $x^n = (1+a)^n \geq 1+an$. Now choose $N$ such that: $1+aN = M$. Thus $N = \dfrac{M-1}{a}$. Then if $n > N$ then $1+an> 1+aN = M$. Thus: $x^n = (1+a)^n \geq 1+an > M$. Done.

Comment: fantastic thank you- how on earth did you think to use Bernoulli?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer with respect to your first sentence "Could somebody ...".

Let $x > 1$. Note that $x^{n} > \log x^{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$. Since $\log x^{n} = n\log x \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, we have $x^{n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I am in the stage of an Analysis course where we have not yet defined what logarithms are- not allowed to use logs, thank you though

Comment: Okay, no problem. :)